# how to use javascript functions?

Tags: php, javascript, function

I have a function to encode strings(I found it from net), and its javascript. but I'm not familiar with js so please help to use this!

this the code:

```
function encode($string) {
var one=new Array([1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]);
var zero=new Array([0,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]);
var a=new Array();var b=new Array();var c=new Array();
var i;for($i=0;$i<$string.length;$i++) a[$i]=$string.charAt($i);
for($i=0;$i<a.length;$i++) a[$i]=a[$i].charCodeAt(0);
for($i=0;$i<a.length;$i++) {
   b[$i]=new Array();$j=0;
   while(a[$i]) {
       b[$i][$j++]=a[$i]%2;a[$i]=parseInt(a[$i]/2);} 
   if($j<8) for($k=$j;$k<8;$k++) b[$i][$k]=0;} 
for($i=0;$i<b.length;$i++) for($j=0;$j<8;$j++) 
   b[$i][$j]=(b[$i][$j]==0)?(zero[(parseInt(Math.random()*10))%5]):(one[(parseInt(Math.random()*10))%4]);
var l=b.length;for($j=0;$j<8;$j++) for($k=0;$k<3;$k++) for($i=0;$i<l;$i++) c[$k*l+$i+$j*3*l]=b[$i][$j][$k];
var fString="";
for($i=0;$i<l*3;$i++) {
   var a=0;for($j=0;$j<8;$j++) a+=c[$j+$i*8]*exp(2,$j);fString+="|"+a;} 
return fString;}
```

as you see this function encode strings and I need this encoded string in a php get request method:

```
"http://example.com/?id="+encode(getId())+"&t="+Math.random()
```

I don't know how to give a string to js functions, please help me by an example of giving some string and at last explain Math.Random() that how much is its range!

Comment: Where is your `getId()` function defined? What does that function contain?

Comment: What do you want to encode? URL query parameter? Is that some kind of special encoding or simply make string safe in URL?

Comment: How do you plan to decode the encoded string ?

Comment: `and at last explain Math.Random() that how much is its range` I'm sorry, but what stops you from entering Math.random in google and read its documentation?

Comment: @nickb its nothing special, just a simple string

Comment: @FAngel I read but i couldn't find its range

Comment: @Adder the decoder is php and my friend does that

Comment: Do you have an exp(base,power) function too?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to use this function for? what is its purpose? it seems like it's doing a lot of work, but I don't get what it's doing it for. You appear to be wanting to use it to hide the value of an ID, but (a) this function doesn't really appear to be designed for that, and (b) if the ID is available in Javascript to be encoded, then the user already has access to it, so there's no point encoding it. Please give more details of what you're trying to do, because I have a feeling the whole thing is unnecessary.

Comment: [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) one of the first links in google, first statement in summary. Everything you might want to know about range.

Comment: Please show a link where you found that encode function.

Comment: Is `getId()` written in PHP or Javascript.

Comment: @Spudley there is a form and user gives a string and js encodes it and with that query it sends it to a php file and the php file decodes it! All these are for that if someone found the name of that php file he can't use it easily!

Comment: @nickb its in Javascript in the same js file

Comment: @FAngel yes you are right! sorry, I should pay more attention! :(

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought. It's not going to work, I'm afraid. The trouble is that it would be very easy for anyone to simply get the ID from javascript before it was encoded, so you're not going to stop anyone. The way to do this is to make sure that the user has permission to do what they're doing (ie they're logged in). Once you've got a valid login, there's no point encoding the IDs; you just need to ensure the server only allows them to load/save records with IDs that they have permission to work with. Then it doesn't matter if they see the ID or not, because they can't do anything bad.

Comment: @Spudley yeah I know that but the use of website is an ordinary work(Sorry they don't allow me to tell) and our UX adviser said not to do that because our visitors gets low, just I want to know how to give a string and how to get the encoded string

Comment: If its possible please give me a jsfiddle.com link to check there

Comment: See below in Answer 1 for jsFiddle.

Comment: @Nermia - I don't understand what you mean by "our visitors get low", but I disagree with your UX adviser. If it's for security, then he is **wrong**. If it's just for making things look better, then I don't really see how this achieves that.

Comment: @Adder Yeah I have a exp(base,expo) function ,too! why you asked this?!

Comment: @Nermia I created a jsFiddle (see below), and it was not going to work until I provided my own version of exp(2,expo).

Answer (score 1):

You would give a string to a js function the way you would in any other language really

```
var a = function(str){alert(str)}
a("This is a string")
```

Math contains a bunch of utility functions to do some mathematical operations.
Math.random() generates a random number between 0 and 1

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle provided of the function with the exp function replaced by equivalent and faster code: http://jsfiddle.net/kAk5G/